# Replace Parent WordPress Title Tags in Child Theme Function

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, title

Is it possible to replace the HTML of a WordPress' parent theme's title tags? I'd like to know how.

A lot of SEO plugins adjust the title tags of themes with wp_title but often developers add additional characters and words like `<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(' - ', true, 'left'); ?></title>`.

I've started to develop the following inside the child theme's functions.php:

```
function set_title($HTMLstr, $content)
{
    return preg_replace('/<title>(.*)\</title>/i', wp_title() , $HTMLstr);
}
```

Comment: Could you just edit the html code of the theme header files directly to change the content?

Comment: That's the way I'm currently doing it but it's a poor design habit as updates overwrite such changes.

Answer (score 0):

You want a "filter", which is a function that can modify the value of arbitrary data based on a filter name.

The filter you want is called "wp_title"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

You would set it up something like:

```
function set_title( $title, $sep ) {
    return "Custom title";
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'set_title', 10, 2 );
```

The "10" may need raised so that this filter applies after any filters in your parent theme. You can access the $title and $sep values as well, which will be passed through other filters too.

Filters typically go in functions.php.

Comment: Clarified my question. Adjusting wp_title is not a solution.